# python : IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python

i wrote this program :

```
l = []
N = int(input("enter the size of the list"))
if N < 50:
  for i in range(N):
      a = int(input("add a number to the list"))
      l.append(a)
  for i in range(N):
      del l[min(l)]
      print(l)
```

and when i run it they say

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<pyshell#5>", line 2, in <module> 
del l[min(l)]  
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

please do you have any solutions ??

Comment: What do you precisely want to do at this step `del l[min(l)]` ? Consider a list `[10, 20, 30]` now image the execution of `del l[min(l)]`. This would be `del l[10]`, but there is not 10th element in the list and hence shows error

Comment: Suppose l is [23, 42, 99]. Then `del l[min(l)]` is equivalent to `del l[23]`, which is equivalent to "delete the 24th element of l". But l doesn't have 24 elements, it has three elements.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `del l[min(l)]` is trying to reference the list item at index `min(l)`.  Let's assume that your list has 3 items in it:

```
l = [22,31,17]
```

Trying to delete the item at the index `min(l)` is referencing the index 17, which doesn't exist.  Only indices 0, 1, and 2 exist.

I think what you want to do is remove the smallest item from your list sequentially.  There are a number of ways to do this.  The method that is **closest** to what you have written would be:

```
for i in range(N):
    l.remove(min(l))
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
del l[min(l)]
```

to

```
del l[l.index(min(l))]
```

Reason : Because you want to delete element holding index **of** min element and **not** index=min element

O/P : (for input 1 2 3 4 5)

[2, 3, 4, 5]

[3, 4, 5]

[4, 5]

[5]

[]